# use tbb::task in event driven application

Tags: c++, tbb

I don't know if it is suitable or preferred to use tbb::task instead of boost::thread in event driven application. Is there anyone encounter before?

sample code:

```
class ProcessA 
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        //do something
    }
};

class ProcessB 
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        //do something
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{     
    task_group group;

    // recv a message
    if (type = MsgA)
    {
      group.run(ProcessA());
    }
    else
    {
      group.run(ProcessB());
    }

    group.wait();

    return(0);
}
```